# Facebook api 2.2 Uninstall application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application on Facebook and I want to remove user's data from my server when he/she removes my application from [here](https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/apps). I was looking for such api on [Facebook Technical Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs) but I did not find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook can send your app a notification when a user removes the app, it's called the [Deauthorization Callback](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.3#deauth-callback) and sends you the user ID so you know the user removed your app